# async rest api product can't set `enable_qty_increments`

Tags: rest-api, stock, qty-increment, manage-stock

I would set up `enable_qty_increments` in my store. I've edit store settings cart options to manage this but when I try to use rest api to update my product always this request can't set options relate to this configuration.

This is an example request

```
curl -X PUT \
  https://xxx.xxxx.xxx/rest/all/async/V1/products/sku_prod \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
  -d '{"product":{"sku":"sku_prod","name":"name","extension_attributes":{"stock_item":{"qty":100,"is_in_stock":true,"is_qty_decimal":false,"min_sale_qty":2,"qty_increments":2,"enable_qty_increments":true}}}}'
```

Actual result contains this value for `stock_item` field

```
"stock_item": {
            "item_id": 109545,
            "product_id": 109591,
            "stock_id": 1,
            "qty": 100,
            "is_in_stock": true,
            "is_qty_decimal": false,
            "show_default_notification_message": false,
            "use_config_min_qty": true,
            "min_qty": 0,
            "use_config_min_sale_qty": 0,
            "min_sale_qty": 1,
            "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
            "max_sale_qty": 10000,
            "use_config_backorders": true,
            "backorders": 1,
            "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
            "notify_stock_qty": 0,
            "use_config_qty_increments": false,
            "qty_increments": 1,
            "use_config_enable_qty_inc": false,
            "enable_qty_increments": true,
            "use_config_manage_stock": true,
            "manage_stock": true,
            "low_stock_date": null,
            "is_decimal_divided": false,
            "stock_status_changed_auto": 0
        }
```

**`"min_sale_qty": 1`** and **`"qty_increments": 1`** have a different values in response w.r.t. values provided by request. Is it a bug or have I a miss configuration in my store?

Please let's me know and thanks in advance